# You have entered wrong captcha code

Tags: php, forms, session, captcha

I have two forms on the same page importing them from iframes..so on the page ff.php i have form1.php and form2.php both have same script of captcha..but the form fields are different from each other now the problem is When i type the right captcha it shows u have entered wrong captcha...though I also specify captcha session differently as

For form1.php captcha session is different:

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            $captcha->session_var = 'captcha1';
            $tuCurl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
            $tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl); 
            curl_close($tuCurl); 
            $userip = explode(',',$tuData);
            $ipcountry = str_replace('"', '', $userip[3]);
```

For form2.php captcha session is different:

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            $captcha->session_var = 'captcha2';
            $tuCurl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
            $tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl); 
            curl_close($tuCurl);
```

Comment: i think may be when ur creating second captcha ur repalacing first captcha.....check with print_r($_session).

Comment: Sorry sir I didnt get u?

Comment: after submiting the form place print_r($_session)..this will show the sessions values of both captcha...check the values with captcha image once..

Comment: I placed it sir but nothing had shown on the browser..nothing means the same problem occuring captcha is wrong

Comment: can u give me the demo page url of that

Comment: Sir actually it is quiet professional so i cant disclose the url socially. Sorry hope u understand

Comment: I think both captcha names are same change form2.php $captcha->session_var = 'captcha2'; to $captcha2->session_var = 'captcha2'; and check once